# Aries blueprint and system properties

Tags: apache, osgi, blueprint, aries

I'd like to get system properties (e.g. username) and pass them as properties to a bean in aries blueprint. Something to pass on a property placeholder default, like username or computername from system properties:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="placeholder" persistent-id="config">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="group.password" value="${username}" />
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>
```

or pass it on to a bean, like this:

```
<bean id="mapStoreConfig" class="com.acme.mypackage.MyBean">
    <property name="enabledp" value="${username}" />
</bean>
```

I've searched and searched but can't find any explanation how to do this. Should I use env:username or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" 
    xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0">

    <ext:property-placeholder placeholder-prefix="$[" placeholder-suffix="]" />
</blueprint>
```

Comment: Thanks Christian with your help I could do it. Actually I even found it now on internet adding the "placeholder-prefix" to the search. I came up with this:                                  `<!-- Allow the use of system properties -->
    <ext:property-placeholder placeholder-prefix="$[" placeholder-suffix="]" />` and the explanation that using this line of code allows blueprint to have access to the system variables.